# Finding previously upvoted comments

Tags: support, comment, up-votes

I upvoted a comment that I found intriguing. However, it crossed my mind again and I couldn't remember on which post it was. Is there any way I can find it? Or should I browse through my browser history?

Comment: [meta.se]: [How can I see comments that I've upvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148008)

Comment: Thank you @MartinSleziak. Spot on as always. Would you mind posting this as an answer so that i accept it?

Answer (score 2):

No, unlike [upvotes to posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote) there is no list of comments you've upvoted.

If you remember some words in it, you can use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1254255/comment-search?score=1) to list the comments with a score of 1 or higher and visit each one of them to check if you upvoted it. Please note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so very recent comments don't appear in it yet.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! The SEDE query can definitely be helpful for any future purposes. However, my search proved to be inconclusive, perhaps because the comment i liked was well above 5 years old.